# Setting Access Role for Event Stream Created Via CloudFormation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to add a dynamodb stream with the following template.yml

```
MyFunc:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./myfunc
      Handler: main
      Runtime: go1.x
      Events:
        MyStream:
          Type: DynamoDB
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt MyTable.StreamArn
            BatchSize: 1
            StartingPosition: LATEST
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
```

However, I'm getting the following error during the deploy stage:

```
Please ensure the role can perform the GetRecords, GetShardIterator, DescribeStream, and ListStreams Actions on your stream in IAM.
```

**Attempt 1**

So I tried fixing the problem by adding the following policies to my IAM, CodeStarWorker-myproject-CloudFormation:

```
"dynamodb:GetRecords",
"dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
"dynamodb:DescribeStream",
"dynamodb:ListStreams",
```

That didn't work, still giving me the same error

**Attempt 2**

Tried using policies stead of role in template.yml

```
MyFunc:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./myfunc
      Handler: main
      Runtime: go1.x
      Events:
        MyStream:
          Type: DynamoDB
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt MyTable.StreamArn
            BatchSize: 1
            StartingPosition: LATEST
      Policies: 
        - IAMFullAccess
        - AWSLambdaFullAccess
```

But it gave me the following error

```
API: iam:CreateRole User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-xxx-CloudFormation/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/awscodestar-xxx-lambda-MyFuncRole-1BO7G545IR5IC
```

**Attempt 3**

Specifying a role in template.yml

```
LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow #allow lambda to assume this role
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LambdaRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow # allow to write logs to cloudwatch
              Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
            - Effect: Allow # allow lambda to read from the event stream
              Action:
              - dynamodb:DescribeStream
              - dynamodb:GetRecords
              - dynamodb:GetShardIterator
              - dynamodb:ListStreams
              Resource: "*"
```

And assign it to MyFunc

```
Role:
  Fn::GetAtt: [ LambdaRole , Arn ]
```

However, it's also giving me the same error indicating that I'm not authorized to perform `iam:CreateRole`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

iam:CreateRole - you would need this action to create a role. The user that you use to run the Cloudformation template would need to include the "CreateRole" action.

Comment: In my second attempt, I have added IAMFullAccess but still giving me the error

Comment: you are creating a new policy which has full access to IAM, you would need access to IAM to create a role using cloudformation. you need talk with your admin to get IAM access to your account to a create role.

Comment: You -> Cloudformation -> Role (error says that you dont have access to create role with cloud formation)